# Eagle create board from schematic is missing some parts but ERC says they are consistent

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I have capacitors C1 through C6 on my schematic, and if I type MOVE C2 into the command line it grabs that capacitor.  But on the board created from my schematic, it is missing C2 and C3 and no other parts (that I have noticed).  If I type MOVE C2 it says C2 does not exist.  When I run ERC it says my board and schematic are consistent.  I have no idea what to make of this, I can't find this anywhere online.  Both capacitors in questions connect a node to GND and on the board layout the capacitor and connection to GND don't exist at all

Comment: I edited your question to only ask one question. If you want to ask about the other issue, you should post it as a new question.

Comment: Do those capacitors have footprints defined?   Any error messages when generating the netlist, or importing it into the PCB program?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out thanks to Peter Bennett's comment.  I had used the SPICE symbol for two of my capacitors when I added a part instead of an actual device that has size specs, and those don't show up on the board.